# Correct wpa_supplicant config for WPA2-Personal connection

Tags: pi-3b+

I need to setup my pi 3b+ headlessly (I dont have access to a monitor or keyboard). I have already burnt raspbian lite to my sd and added the ssh and wpa_supplicant.conf files. However, the pi does not seem to appear connected to the network at all (according to tools like Fing on my android phone).

My network has a WPA2-Personal password. My current wpa_supplicant.conf is below,

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="RouterName"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    group=CCMP TKIP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Any potential fixes are welcome.

Comment: Remove those ```key=```, ```group=``` and ```auth=``` lines they aren't needed for a connection to a simple home router running WPA2.

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Dougie I set the config without the key, group and auth settings and still wont appear connected to the network. Is there a headless setup step I'm missing?

Comment: Where did you put the wpa_supplicant.conf file? And does it disappear after you boot the Pi with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address). If you don't find the solution there then make a question explaining why.

Comment: @Dirk I added it to /boot. After booting the pi however, the files still remain on the SD Card.

Comment: So on the computer on which you wrote the SD card you put it in /boot? That's not correct. It should be in the root of the first (FAT) partition of the SD card, not in a subdirectory. The file is removed after processing.

Comment: @Dirk I meant to say the FAT partition called boot

Comment: Thanks for making me type a bunch of info based on incorrect information. Please try to get the details correct in future... If the file does not get removed then there is something wrong with your setup or your typing skills (typos). Try with a fresh download of Raspbian Stretch (Lite), triple check the name of the file, etc.  Don't think I will be contributing to this issue any further, though. Good luck!